# how to make a prescrollable tab control so i can add in tons of text boxes without having the form not take up the entire screen

Tags: c#, forms, scrollbar

so I have a tab control in my c# program that's going to be getting a lot of information from a user. this is in the form of like 40 checkboxes/textboxes. I'm trying to figure out how in the designer to add a scroll bar ahead of time so I can have the form be a nice 800x500 but allow the user to scroll threw all the boxes and fill them up. idk if this is possible in the designer, or if I need to add them in through code with like a loop or something and then have autoscrollbar on so it works that way. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a datagridview! Much less work, much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Open the designer. Select your tab page in the Properties window. Set `AutoScroll` property to `True`. Expand `AutoScrollMinSize` property and enter some value (let say 1000) for `Height`. Now your tab page should have a vertical scrollbar.